# Проблема с cookies в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.6

Как сохранить информацию, указанную пользователем, в cookies? Пользователь должен указать своё имя в поле, после чего оно сохранится в cookies и приветствие с именем должно всегда отображаться на странице.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import UserForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Hello, {0}</h2>".format(name))
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        return render(request, "firstapp\index.html", {"form": userform})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Django</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

Comment: И какая у вас проблема?

Comment: Я же написал, мне нужно сохранить введённые пользователем данные в cookies. Есть поле для ввода имени. После ввода отображается приветствие, нужно сделать так, чтобы введённое имя сохранялось в cookies.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать это на клиентской стороне, к джанго это не имеет отношения